# Looking for this short story where Egyptian pharaoh visits modern convenience store and punchline is it's more impressive than a pyramid

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I remember reading this within the last two years or so but I cannot find it on google (it might have died since I read it). It was a short story of some kind written on maybe a blog? The author/narrator wrote it as a long-winded argument/explanation on how a modern convenience store like a 7-eleven was more technically impressive than an Egyptian pyramid. The store appeared next to the pyramid in ancient times, the Pharaoh visited it and marveled at things we take for granted like cameras, heaters, hot dogs, chocolate, etc. Whereas the pyramid was an elaborate block of stone.